# How to convert the files in an audio playlist to one large audio file?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, convert

I have created an audio playlist file (m3u) from a list of around 40 mp3s. I need to be able to combine/join these files into one large audio file (mp3 or wav) that maintains the order that they are in in the playlist file. Is there software - command line or gui - that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If they are all in the same directory, you can just `cat` them to the output file.

  ```
  cat *.mp3 > output.mp3
  ```
- If the file names do not reflect the order that they appear in the playlist follow [this tutorial](https://dominichosler.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/moving-and-transcoding-an-m3u-playlist-with-a-bash-script/) to rename them accordingly.

---

- To read the contents of the playlist file and then cat each song in turn,

  ```
  while read -r line; do cat "$line"; done < playlist.m3u > output.mp3
  ```

  Note that this will give you one mp3 file containing all the songs, the metadata will probably not be correct. The output file will play fine though. (I've just tried it).

Comment: They are in the same directory but they are not listed in the same way as they are in the playlist file.

Comment: @hellocatfood Please see modified answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works though I had to reencode it.